# Reload Specific part of the Page with JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My Problem is that I have got a full page and after I perform some tasks on the Web server, the Database has Changed, now I immediately want to display these changes to the User, when I load for example the Page `/admin/accounts/users`, I receive a page, after clicking the delete button, I want the `#main` part of this page to reload. How can I achieve this?

With This Code: 
I've got something like this:

```
<main id="main">
    <main id="main">
      <div class="row">

      </div>
    </main>
</main>
```

But i want it to be:

```
<main id="main">
    <div class="row">
    </div>
</main>
```

Thats my JS-Code:

```
$(".torero-task").click(function() {
   var element = $(this);
    $.post(element.attr("torero-cmd"), {csrf_token: "#csrf_content#", id: element.attr("torero-id")}, function (data) {
        if(data.error == true) {
            swal("Attention please!", data.message , "error", {
                button: "Hm, okay!",
            });
        } else {
            swal("Success!", data.message, "success", {
                button: "Verstanden",
            }).then(function() {
                $("#main").load("/admin/" + element.attr("torero-reload-page") + " #main");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Move you click callback function to a named function and call it as needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery Ajax which will help you reload only the div

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

or you can do this by

```
$("#main").load(location.href + " #main");
```

Comment: Actually the Correct Answer was:                     $("#main").load(location.href + " #main>*"); Otherwise i would have another main inside the main :D